# Error installing Django CMS

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm very new to Django/Python. I just installed Django 1.8 yesterday. The client needs a Django CMS setup. I followed the necessary steps on the Django CMS website to install it on my Mac and it keeps erroring out:

[image]

The help guide talks about library dependencies. And I don't even understand the error well enough to know if that's the problem. I installed Pillow, not sure if that was necessary..

https://djangocms-installer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/libraries.html 
I don't understand what any of this means and if this is related. Do I need any of these libraries to make it work? None of those commands look like the install commands I'm used to.

Comment: The first error I can see is "Permission denied" when writing to `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django_treebeard-4.1.0.dist-info`. As a separate question, are you trying to install django and the CMS in a virtual environment? If not, you should take a look at using them.

Comment: You say you "just installed django 1.8 yesterday", was that for this project or were you emphasising that you are new to django? I only ask as I followed the steps to install django cms on the project page (https://www.django-cms.org/en/) and it all worked fine. The only time I needed to run anything as a super user was to upgrade `virtualenv` and/or `pip`. Have you followed the steps shown?

Comment: Last question before I go to bed... why does the client _need_ a **django** cms? If you are not familiar with django why not use Wordpress, Drupal or some other CMS that can be easily installed?

Comment: The client has every other project in Django. We are a PHP house, yes. But they are paying us to learn and requested a CMS. I installed Django and Python yesterday and started watching tutorials. And today learned about their CMS request and tried to set it up

Comment: Can you confirm if you have followed the steps shown on the project page? It should not be necessary to install django or pillow manually, in the test I performed all dependencies are automatically installed. And have you upgraded `pip` and `virtualenv`? e.g. `$ pip install --upgrade pip` and `$ pip install --upgrade virtualenv`

Comment: "...they are paying us to learn..." - say no more ;)

Comment: Yes, both pip and virtualenv are already up to date. New error: when I try doing $ djangocms -f -p . website, I'm getting the error "/usr/bin/python: can't open file '/usr/bin/django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory" Help guide says: "djangocms-installer assumes that django-admin.py is installed in the same directory as python executable, which is the standard virtualenv layout." I don't know where those 2 files are and how to find them. But if it's the standard, why is this an issue? Where is usr dir? My root dir is Users..

Comment: Also when I create the env dir from virtualenv, both the DjangoCMS and virtualenv don't say anything about this, but when I create the djangocms project do I need to cd into that env? The installation guide doesn't say to cd into it, but how does it work if the project dir is alongside the env dir? I'm so very lost.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130642/discussion-between-tony-and-pinksharpii).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally figure this out. Even though I swear I did this initially, pretty much any step along the way had to be done with sudo. Not sure why, as there are no strange permissions set up on my computer. As a separate issue, I had to change the permissions of the sqlite db after it got all setup as well.

Comment: I also upgraded to Python 3.5 instead of using 2.7 and I had none of these issues. I did not need to use sudo either.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

cd into the directory where you store all your projects

And now:

Create virtualenv

```
virtualenv my_new_project
```

Change to new virtualenv

```
cd my_new_project
```

Activate virtualenv

```
source bin/activate
```

Install djangocms-installer

```
pip install djangocms-installer
```

Setup a new django CMS site

```
djangocms my_new_site
```

Comment: Again, I am getting the error "/usr/bin/python: can't open file '/usr/bin/django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Comment: can you provide me with the full traceback? Its strange it looks in /usr/bin/ as it should look in the virtualenv.

Comment: Yeah I still don't understand this. I did comment with my solution - lots of permissions issues.